# send and receive transaction in bitcoin

Tags: php, bitcoin

How to send and receive transaction using bitcoin address.
I am using [this url](http://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api).
I have only Bitcoin addresses for send and receive.
Also i do not have a My Wallet account.

I have used below code.

```
$to = // Bitcoin address1
$from = // Bitcoin address2
$json_url = "https://blockchain.info/merchant/d15dea6639d24b81e5caefad8aa4b0c6831cdccf1c21f8c234fd568d40e4238d/payment?to=$to&amount=5000&from=$from";
```

I got below error.

```
"You must provide a recipient address"
```

Thanks all.

Comment: I think you need to use a password in the API call.

Comment: beware relying on https security now that it has been cracked by the nsa. http://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/sep/05/nsa-gchq-encryption-codes-security

Answer (score 0):

You need a wallet at blockchain.info in order to send/receive funds using the "My Wallet API": https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api

If you are going to use this API I have a PHP class I use for interactions with my blockchain wallet: https://github.com/lukesims/Blockchain-API-PHP-Class You may find it useful.

If you just want to receive payments then use the "Receive Payments API" which is different. I cannot post more than 2 links, but the blockchain developer section makes a pretty obvious distinction between the two.

Answer (score -1):

Simply just fill in the information below...  You need an account with BlockChain to send payments.  You don't need an account to receive, however.  This is just sending, not a callback.  If you're looking for a callback read further into the documentation.

https://blockchain.info/merchant/$guid/payment?password=$main_password&second_password=$second_password&to=$address&amount=$amount&from=$from&shared=$shared&fee=$fee¬e=$note

```
<?php

$guid="GUID_HERE";
$firstpassword="PASSWORD_HERE";
$secondpassword="PASSWORD_HERE";
$amounta = "10000000";
$amountb = "400000";
$addressa = "1A8JiWcwvpY7tAopUkSnGuEYHmzGYfZPiq";
$addressb = "1ExD2je6UNxL5oSu6iPUhn9Ta7UrN8bjBy";
$recipients = urlencode(json_encode(
    array(
        $addressa => $amounta,
        $addressb => $amountb
    )
));

$json_url = "https://blockchain.info/merchant/$guid/sendmany?password=$firstpassword&second_password=$secondpassword&recipients=$recipients";

$json_data = file_get_contents($json_url);

$json_feed = json_decode($json_data);

$message = $json_feed->message;
$txid = $json_feed->tx_hash;

?>
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this but should point out that should be https not http as it's exposing pws.